# The type or namespace name 'SqlServer' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Synchronization.Data'

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

This is a strange problem I'm having, I've downloaded the WebSharingAppDemo sample from Microosfts website but when I try to compile it in Visual Studio 2008 I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'SqlServer' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.Synchronization.Data'

When attempting to use the Microsoft.Synchronizaqtion.Data.SqlServer.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add a reference to **Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer**

*Right-Click project*
*Choose Add Reference...*
*Find and add **Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer** under the **.NET** tab*

If you can't find it in the list, you may need to install the **Microsoft Sync Framework**:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23217

and/or **SQL Server 2008 Express**:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1695

Comment: I can add Microsoft.Synchronization.data.SqlServerCE but none with just SqlServer, I've already installed SQL Server and the sync framework.

Comment: I would confirm first that it really isn't in the .NET references list (just the other day I had the same problem, but then I realized I was just missing it in between the .Data.Server and .Data.SqlServerCE lines). Failing that, try using the browse tab to go to Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Microsoft Sync Framework\v2.0 and manually select Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.dll. Failing that, I would reinstall Microsoft Sync Framework.