# Namespace "Microsoft.SqlServer.MessageBox" Does Not Exist

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the `Microsoft.SqlServer.MessageBox.ExceptionMessageBox` class for an application.

After putting `using Microsoft.SqlServer.MessageBox;` at the top of my program like [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166340.aspx) stated, I got the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'SqlServer' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Trying to add a reference to the required assembly like [this cite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166341.aspx) said didn't help either; the DLL wasn't present, nor was the folder it was supposed to be in.

**Question:**  How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900632/the-type-or-namespace-name-sqlserver-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsof

Comment: You need to have SQL installed to have those bits. It may have other dependencies in the same directory

Comment: I'm curious why you want to use a message box from that namespace. What kind of app are you using? Where are you going to deploy it?

Comment: @Flydog57 it's just an XNA application.  i want any exceptions that are thrown to be shown in a message box before closing the program

Answer (score 0):

You may need to dd a reference to the below assembly.

> Microsoft.ExceptionMessageBox.dll

You might have to browse for it.The default installation directory is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\##\SDK\Assemblies.

Comment: That directory doesn't seem to exist.  I tried looking under `C:\Program Files (x86)` and found nothing as well.